# addEventListener to some tag names with for loop - Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I would like to add an eventlistener to div tag names (around 30 div tags), as you can see this option is not possible and I would like to do it with for loop, but I got 2 errors.

```
var myDiv = document.getElementsByTagName("div");


for(var i=0; i<myDivs.length; i++){
    myDiv[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function(event){
        myDiv[i].style.background = 'purple';
    })

    myDiv[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function(event){
        myDiv[i].style.background = 'white';
    })

}
```

**Error 1:**

Uncaught TypeError: myDiv[i].addEventListener is not a function
    at script.js:5

**Error 2:**

script.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'background' of undefined
    at HTMLDivElement. (script.js:6)

Comment: Don't use `for ... in` on array or array-like structures it will likely iterate over other non-numerical properties, use `for ... of` or regular for loop

Comment: `div:hover { background-color: purple }`

Comment: Change to `for(var i = 0; i < myDiv.length; i++){`

Comment: And `myDiv[i].style.background ` to `this.style.background `

Comment: @LGSon - script.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous>

Comment: @LGSon, Working Great!! Thanks a lot ;)